# After running npm i --save react-router-dom i am getting error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am getting the error shown below after running the `react-router-dom` command
how to fix this?

> ./node_modules/create-react-context/lib/implementation.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\learn-router\node_modules\create-react-context\lib'

Comment: npm install try this

Comment: try this: npm i react-router-dom --save

Comment: @Ramya, did u resolve the issue ?

Comment: I have deleted my Package-lock.json file..then i installed npm now its working fine.. Thank u srinivas

Comment: cool. thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

you have to install react first before installing react-router-dom package,

try this:

```
 rm -rf node_modules
 npm i react react-router-dom --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `react-router-dom` directly to `dependencies` list in `package.json` file.

```
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
```

then run below command in your project root directory.

```
npm install
```

[image]